# Class not registered COM DI API PHP

Tags: php, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I'm trying to use SAP DI API for SAP B1 with PHP.

I'm using COM object like this :

```
<?php
try
{
    $CompDI = new COM("SAPbobsCOM.Company");
    $CompDI->server = "193.0.0.241\SAP";
    $CompDI->CompanyDB = "Company_Test";
    $CompDI->username = "username";
    $CompDI->password = "password";
    $ReturnCode = $CompDI->Connect;
    echo $CompDI->CompanyName;
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

But I got this error :

> Failed to create COM object `SAPbobsCOM.Company': Class not
>   registered

If I change the spelling of "Company", I got this error :

> Failed to create COM object `SAPbobsCOM.Company': Incorrect syntax

So I think it finds the class but can't load it, I've got not idea where the problem came from...

Thank you in advance !

Comment: are you running this application in a system where the DI API Com classes are registered correctly? OR correct SAP B1 [32/64 bit] client is installed

Comment: Yes DI Api is intalled and SAP B1 too

Comment: okay, you need to make sure your web application pool allows 32 bit applications if your application is 32 bit. I mean in IIS i get this error when that is not configured.

Answer (score 1):

I saw these errors in the following cases, Please check any one of it helps you or not.

1. DI API and SAP B1 client not installed
2. Application is 32 Bit but the DI API/Client installed is 64bit or vise versa
3. Application is 32 bit and Web application pool is not enabled with 32-bit applications

[image]

Comment: It's been six years, yet in the vast SAP swamp this is the first concise list of criteria I was able to find for this issue.

Comment: Hehe.. interesting to know. :)